# Spring Cache not creating proxy class

Tags: java, spring, caching, proxy, aop

I am trying to add a cache on a component bean and spring is not creating the proxy class. If I put the @Cacheable on the repo then it works just fine. I'm verifying this currently just by looking inside the cacheManager after each invocation. What am I doing wrong here??

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("clientids");
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheDelegator {

    private final RepoUser getFromRepo;

    public ClientReference getId(String email) {
        return getFromRepo.getFromRepo(email).orElseThrow(() ->
                new ClientNotFoundException(ExceptionType.NOT_FOUND));
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RepoUser {

    private final ClientRepository repository;

    @Cacheable("clientids")
    Optional<ClientReference> getFromRepo(String email) {
        return repository.findClientIdByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientReference, Long> {

    Optional<ClientReference> findClientIdByEmail(String email);

}
```

I know this is a roundabout way of doing it. I'm trying to understand how the cache interceptors are being created though.

Comment: You rmethod needs to be `public`. Spring AOP is proxy based and therefor only works on `public` and `protected` methods not on `private` or default access (like yours) methods.

Comment: Thanks.. I thought of that a second after posting this and was checking it :) Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Deinum above. My method needed to be public.